# What is the flow of this program? I already know the output but I want to know how to get there

Tags: java

```
public class MainClassInheritance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Animal("Animal");
        Animal shark = new AquaticAnimal("Dolphin");
        Animal horse = new TerrestialAnimal("Horse");
        Animal lion = new WildAnimal("Tiger");
        System.out.println(horse);
    }
}
class Animal {
    public Animal() {
        System.out.println("Animal!");
    }
    public Animal(String name) {
        this(name, 0);
    }
    public Animal(String name, int legs) {
        System.out.println(
                name + " has " + (legs == 0 ? "no" : legs) + " legs");
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm an animal!";
    }
}
class AquaticAnimal extends Animal {
    public AquaticAnimal() {
        System.out.println("AquaticAnimal!");
    }
    public AquaticAnimal(String name) {
        this(name, 0);
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    public AquaticAnimal(String name, int legs) {
        System.out.println(
                name + " has " + (legs == 0 ? "no" : legs) + " legs");
    }
}
class TerrestialAnimal extends Animal {
    public TerrestialAnimal() {
        System.out.println("TerrestialAnimal!");
    }
    public TerrestialAnimal(String name) {
        this(name, 4);
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    public TerrestialAnimal(String name, int legs) {
        super(name, legs);
        System.out.println(
                name + " has " + (legs == 0 ? "no" : legs) + " legs");
    }
}
class WildAnimal extends TerrestialAnimal {
    public WildAnimal() {
        System.out.println("WildAnimal!");
    }
    public WildAnimal(String name) {
        this(name, 4);
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    public WildAnimal(String name, int legs) {
        System.out.println(
                name + " has " + (legs == 0 ? "no" : legs) + " legs");
    }
}
```

I am genuinely interested in grasping the concepts of computer science problem-solving. I have a strong desire to explore the fascinating world of algorithms, data structures, and programming languages.
I also tried chatGPT but it gave me the wrong answer.
I want to understand the output of the program.
which is:

```
Animal has no legs
Animal!
Dolphin has no legs
Dolphin
Horse has 4 legs
Horse has 4 legs
Horse
Animal!
TerrestialAnimal!
Tiger has 4 legs
Tiger
I'm an animal!
```

Comment: I suggest that you use a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Each of those bracketed structures, `{ }`, are containers for data.  You can access the data of the containers, from other containers.

Answer (score 0):

call "super constructor"

like this....

```
class AquaticAnimal extends Animal {
    public AquaticAnimal() {
        System.out.println("AquaticAnimal!");
    }
    public AquaticAnimal(String name) {
        this(name, 0);
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    public AquaticAnimal(String name, int legs) {
        super(name, legs);
        System.out.println(
                name + " has " + (legs == 0 ? "no" : legs) + " legs");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to see a little more understanding of the concept of inheritance in object-oriented languages.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).